How to integrate uploadthing with react-hook-forms?
I'm trying to create a page that allows users to upload a file and the user has to fill out a form with a title and description. Once submit button is hit, An email is sent which includes the title and description from the form, as well as the uploaded items url. I am using react-hook-forms and uploadthing for uploading files.
I have created a state variable that stores the uploaded item's url. How do I pass this to the form when using react-hook-form?
